# Cannot run an .exe program by using Process.Start() in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, process.start

I have a problem when I using Process.Start() to run an .exe file from Unity. I trying run other one with that code but it works. Here is my code:

```
if (GUI.Button (new Rect (20, 465, 150, 20), "Tháo / Lắp")) {
    Process.Start(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\ThaoLapT64S\\module1.exe");
}
```

I put another .exe or .txt file to same folder but it works, and this file cannot run by the code above. I can run this file normally by double click on it. I think it's a problem with this file. It is a graphic program. Anyone can help me solve this problem. 
Thanks so much!

Comment: Please use unity3d tag for this kind of questions. The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() 
+ "\\ThaoLapT64S\\module1.exe");

processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\ThaoLapT64S\\module1.exe");

Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```